# Encoded traffic python socket

Tags: python, sockets, encoding

I'm trying to set up some client and server code in python that sends encoded traffic. Here is a sample of an echo server that encodes data using `base64`:

```
    import base64,socket

    s=socket.socket()
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1",9090))
    s.listen(5)
    cls,addr=s.accept()
    data=cls.recv(1024)
    cls.send(base64.b64encode(data))
    cls.close()
```

The problem I have encountered is some times large traffic breaks the encoding and decoding process with errors showing incorrect padding. What other encoding methods can I use that will not break when large TCP traffic is sent.

Comment: What is the purpose of the encoding? In other words, why don't just send the raw data?

Answer (score 0):

[`base64`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/base64.html) works by encoding every 3 bytes into 4 bytes. When decoding, it takes those 4 bytes and converts them back to 3 bytes. So...

- If there were less than 3 bytes remaining in the input, the output is
  gets padded with `=` to make it 4 bytes.
- If the input to `b64decode` is not a multiple of 4 bytes you will get
  this exception.

The easiest solution would be to make sure the packets you are sending are always a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: **Please** pay attention when approving suggested edits 'improving' formatting. [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4385056) introduced a syntax error and should have been rejected (the `/` operator was deleted).